# Show this product is invariant under a unitary transformation

Tags: matrices

The transformation is given by a matrix $U$ such that $U^{\dagger}=U^{-1}$, show that $X^{\dagger}X$ is invariant under this transformation.

So I need to show that $X^{\dagger}X = X^{'\dagger}X$ for $X'\rightarrow UX$.

$X^{'\dagger}X = (UX)^{\dagger}X = X^{\dagger}U^{\dagger}X$

That looks to me like it only works if $U^{\dagger}=I$,  have I gone wrong in just the two steps I've done?

Comment: If $X \mapsto UX$ then you should compute $(UX)^{\dagger}(UX)$.

Comment: @Gibbs Sorry that was careless, should've been $X'$ maps to that, edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If the request is to show that $X^{\dagger}X$ is invariant under that transformation, then I think you should compute $(UX)^{\dagger}(UX)$. What is your $X'$?

Comment: @Gibbs I see what you mean, I'm calculating the wrong thing in order to show the invariance. I don't know anything about $X'$ except that $X'\rightarrow UX$.

Comment: Let me know if it works like this.

Comment: @Gibbs It does work, thank you for your help!